# Running msbuild target during docker build causes error

Tags: .net, docker, powershell, msbuild

I use an msbuild target to replace certain values in my .appsettings file.

This is the command:
`<Exec Command="pwsh -Command &quot;$appSettingsPath = '$(AppSettingsFilePath)'; $json = Get-Content $appSettingsPath | ConvertFrom-Json; $json.VersionInfo.AppVersion = '$(VersionMatch)$(VersionSuffixMatch)'; $json | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $appSettingsPath&quot;" />`

This works fine!

However, when running `dotnet build` within a `Dockerfile` the script fails with `MSB3073 Parser Error`

The strange thing is that in the log where it shows the location of the error the `$json` variables are gone.

Log output:  `… vertFrom-Json; .VersionInfo.AppVersion = '1.0.0-preview1';  | Convert …`

I searched a lot, tried escaping the variable, thinking about other solutions but I'm stuck at the moment. I appreciate any hint that can point me to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around that issue by moving my powershell script to a file and call that file from `.targets`

`<Exec Command="pwsh -File update-settings.ps1 $(AppSettingsFilePath) $(VersionMatch) $(VersionSuffixMatch)" />`

Now it is also working during `docker build`